# How to determine size of the C# Object

Tags: c#

I define my object as follows:

```
public class A
{
    public object Result
    {
        get
        {
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            result = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then i am storing some string value inside it as :

```
A.Result=stringArray;
```

here stringArray has 5 string values.
now i want to use that object somewhere else and would like to know the length of string value inside this object. How?

Comment: Which string value? Do you mean length of the 'stringArray'? Or value of each string within this array?

Comment: Did you try to cast to `string[]`?

Comment: actually i want to know that how many string values are stored in A.Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for the length of `Result` if it's a string then you can do the following.

```
var s = Result as string;
return s == null ? 0 : s.Length;
```

---

***Based on your comment while typing all this up. It sounds like the following is what you actually want***

If it's array:

```
var array = Result as string[];
return array == null ? 0 : array.Length;
```

---

or if you want the total length of all the items in the array:

```
var array = Result as string[];
var totalLength = 0;
foreach(var s in array)
{
    totalLength += s.Length;
}
```

If you want to know the size in bytes then you need to know the encoding.

```
var array = Result as string[];
var totalSize = 0;
foreach(var s in array)
{
    //You'll need to know the proper encoding. By default C# strings are Unicode.
    totalSize += Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s).Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array  = A.Result as string[];

if (array != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Length of the object by converting it into array of string.

For Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

        A.Result = new string[] { "il","i","sam","sa","uo"}; //represent as stringArray

        string[] array = A.Result as string[];

        Console.WriteLine(array.Length);

        Console.Read();
}
```

Your object is Invalid so I rewrite:

```
public class A
{
    public static object Result { get; set; } //I change it to static so we can use A.Result;
}
```